# How to get the value of `t` so that my function `h(t)=epsilon` for a fixed `epsilon`?

Tags: r

Following this question:

If I have generated `m=1000` random vectors `x_0` uniformly distributed on the sphere and eigenvectors of a random matrix GOE:

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(101)
n <- 500
#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values
v <- ev$vectors

#sample 1000 x_0
#size of multivariate distribution
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)

#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
xmats <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) initial[i, ]/norm(initial[i, ], type="2"))
```

Define a function `h_1(t)`:

[image]

The code for this function is that

```
# function
h1t <- function(t,x_0) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}
```

I want to find `t_epsilon` so that `h(t_epsilon)=epsilon` for `epsilon=0.01`.

**EDIT:**

Following the answer:

```
find_t <- function(x, epsilon = 0.01, range = c(-50, 50)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}

res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)
```

However, it shows that error

```
Error in uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range, tol = .Machine$double.eps) : 
f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniroot` finds where your function is equal to 0, so you need a wrapper function that subtracts epsilon from your function's output:

```r
find_t <- function(x, epsilon = 0.01, range = c(-50, 50)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t_modefied(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}
```

We *could* use this one at a time on your different matrices to find the t value where the output is equal to epsilon:

```r
x_01t <- find_t(x_01)
x_01t
#> [1] -0.5149889

h1t_modefied(x_01t, x_01)
#> [1] 0.01
```

Or, better still, put all your matrices in a `list` and run the function on all of them with a simple single call to `lapply`:

```r
xmats <- list(x_01 = x_01, x_02 = x_02, x_03 = x_03, x_04 = x_04, x_05 = x_05)

res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)

res
#> $x_01
#> [1] -0.5149889
#> 
#> $x_02
#> [1] -0.2521749
#> 
#> $x_03
#> [1] -0.02756945
#> 
#> $x_04
#> [1] -0.4903002
#> 
#> $x_05
#> [1] -0.3473344
```

And we can see that these are the t values that make your `hit_modefied` function output `epsilon` by feeding these results back into the function via `Map`:

```r
Map(h1t_modefied, t = res, x_0 = xmats)
#> $x_01
#> [1] 0.01
#> 
#> $x_02
#> [1] 0.01
#> 
#> $x_03
#> [1] 0.01
#> 
#> $x_04
#> [1] 0.01
#> 
#> $x_05
#> [1] 0.01
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask that if there is a better way to get `m=10` vectors `x_01, x_02,..., x_010` from `initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=10, mu=mean, Sigma=var)` and normalized? Because I can only write this code one by one by hand now. If I want to experiment with a lot of initial values `x_0`, this is a bit too much trouble.

Comment: Like `1000` different `x_0` from multivariate distribution with l^2 normalized and compute `res<-find_t(x_0)` for each `x_0`. Then we can plot the histogram of `res`.

Comment: Yes, try `xmats <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) initial[i, ]/norm(initial[i, ], type="2"))` to get a list of 1000 matrices (obviously you need 1000 values in `initial` to do this.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my question based on your comments. Now, I have `100` initial value `x_0`. Then I apply your function `res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)` get these values of time `t` so that `h_1(t)=epsilon`. But How to `hist` them? There is an error `Error in hist.default(res) : 'x' must be numeric`.

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry, when I sample `1000` `x_0`, the function `lapply(xmats, find_t)`  report error: `Error in uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range, tol = .Machine$double.eps) : 
f() values at end points not of opposite sign`. How to fit that?

Comment: I just change the size of matrix. Your function works for `n=100` but does not work for `n=500`. How to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: I asked one more question based on your function in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609682/how-to-find-the-value-of-time-t0-so-that-ht-0-01-in-r. Some values in `res` will be negative which is impossible. Because our function is positive. I am not sure how to fix that?