# How to fit it `Error in hist.default(res) : 'x' must be numeric`?

Tags: r

Following this question: [How to get the value of `t` so that my function `h(t)=epsilon` for a fixed `epsilon`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605908/how-to-get-the-value-of-t-so-that-my-function-ht-epsilon-for-a-fixed-epsi)

I first sampling 500 eigenvectors `v` of a random matrix `G` and then generate 100 different random vectors `initial` of dimension `500`. I normalized them in `mats`.

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(100001)
n <- 500
#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values
v <- ev$vectors

#size of multivariate distribution
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)

#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
xmats <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) initial[i, ]/norm(initial[i, ], type="2"))
```

Then I compute `res`

```
h1t <- function(t,x_0) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}

find_t <- function(x, epsilon = 0.01, range = c(-50, 50)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}
```

I want to get `res`:

```
res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)
```

However, it shows error that `Error in uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range, tol = .Machine$double.eps) :  f() values at end points not of opposite sign`

Comment: hist(unlist(res) perhaps?, though it's not very exciting, you're getting the error because res is a list of lists, and hist wants values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` is a `list`. I run `hist(unlist(res))` and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to plot the distribution of 'res`. I can just use `hist(unlist(res),prob=T)`? But it seems not a distribution?

Comment: It would be a parsimoniously small distribution, of two. How many results from your above were you expecting?

Comment: You may change the `breaks` of the `hist` like this: `hist(unlist(res), breaks = 30)` or even use a `density` function inside a `plot` like `plot(density(unlist(res)))`.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask this error `Error in uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range, tol = .Machine$double.eps) : 
f() values at end points not of opposite sign` ? When I change the size of my matrix `n=500`. There would be error on `uniroot`. Can we fix that?

Comment: But it works for `n=100`... I am not sure where is the issue...

Comment: Your question changed substantially after the edition you made! Try to change the `extendInt` argument from `uniroot` to `yes`.