# How to find the value of time `t>0` so that `h(t)=0.01` in R?

Tags: r

Improving this answer in question:[How to get the value of `t` so that my function `h(t)=epsilon` for a fixed `epsilon`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605908/how-to-get-the-value-of-t-so-that-my-function-ht-epsilon-for-a-fixed-epsi).

My question is that:

> Consider a random matrix and sample its eigenvectors `v_i` and eigenvalues `lambda_i`. Given initial data `x_0`, I want to get the hitting time that for a fixed `epsilon=0.01`, `t_n:=\inf\{t>0: h_1(t)\ge \epsilon\}`. Here the function `h_1(t)` is given by
> [image]

I have wrote the code for these setting and function `h_1(t)`:

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(100001)
n <- 300
#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values
v <- ev$vectors

#size of multivariate distribution
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)

#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
xmats <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) initial[i, ]/norm(initial[i, ], type="2"))


h1t <- function(t,x_0) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}
```

I used the answer in that question for finding the hitting time:

```
find_t <- function(x, epsilon = 0.01, range = c(-50, 50)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}

res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)
```

The output `res`:

```
[[995]]
[1] -0.2698699

[[996]]
[1] -0.3138642

[[997]]
[1] -0.4417028

[[998]]
[1] -0.04204563

[[999]]
[1] -0.4150783

[[1000]]
[1] -0.3695955
```

**Question:**
**But this output `res` will contain negative value. How to fix that?**

If I plot the graph of my function `h_1(t)`: we can see that for `epsilon=0.01`, the value of time `t` should be positive... So it seems that here is something wrong in the function `find_t` .

```
h1t <- function(t,x_0=unlist(xmats[1000])) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}

plot(h1t,0,200)
```

[image]

---

Update:

I found that if I choose `n=1000` for the size of matrix, there would be error:

```
Error in uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range, tol = .Machine$double.eps) : 
f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `res`, like the following graph shows. The horizontal line is drawn at `y == epsilon == 0.01`.

You are mistaking the abscissa for the ordinate, that's all.

```r
res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)

curve(h1t, -1, 1, ylim = c(0, 1))
abline(h = 0.01, v = res[[1000]], col = "red", lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The strictly increasing function is defined for `t > 0` but

```
h1t(0)
#> [1] 0.07184164
```

In its domain, there is no `t` for which `h1t(t) == 0.01`.

Comment: Thanks. But why I change `n` at the beginning for the size of matrix, there would be error: `Error in uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range, tol = .Machine$double.eps) : 
f() values at end points not of opposite sign`?

Comment: @oliver Plot the function, if it crosses the horizontal line `abline(h=epsilon)` then you're safe. If not, widen the search `range` until it does.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? How to fit this error for other values of `n`?

Comment: @oliver `uniroot` needs the function to have different signs on the end points of the range interval. See my plot above. The function crosses the horizontal line, at -1 it is below and at 1 it is above the line and since it is continuous there must be a crossing point, a point where `f(x) - epsilon == 0`. If in your case both endpoints have the same sign, plot the function between larger intervals until the function's value changes sign.

Comment: @oliver See the Wikipedia page on the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). `uniroot` uses an algorithm that combines bisection with other algorithms meant to speed up convergence.